# In Nimbus, how to paint TextField when MouseOver?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, nimbus

I recently studied to override the defaults of Nimbus.

In the page of Nimbus Defaults for the TextField, there is no key `TextField[MouseOver].borderPainter` while there is `Button[MouseOver].backgroundPainter`.

I desired to paint TextField when MouseOver as I can do for JButton.

How can I achieve that? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not `override` the `paintComponent()` method of `JTextField` and do custom painting, after setting a flag inside `mouseEntered/mouseExited` methods ?

Comment: But I want to do that in a pluggable look and feel. That's why I overrode the Nimbus UIDefaults. So your suggestion of adding a MouseListener to the text field is not what I want.

Comment: I am sorry, my knowledge in `Pluggable LookAndFeel` is not enough, to provide a valid answer :(

Comment: Nothing, me study too

Answer (score 2):

A button is different than a text field. Even in the default metal LAF the button supports a change of border on a mouse over while a text field doesn't. So I guess it is no surprise that the Nimbus text field doesn't support this property.

You can implement this behaviour yourself by adding a `MouseListener` to the text field. Then you handle the `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` events to change the border.

Comment: But I want to do that in a pluggable look and feel. That's why I overrode the Nimbus UIDefaults. So your suggestion of adding a MouseListener to the text field is not what I want.

Comment: @user2671610 searcvh for custom L&F based on Nimbus, there is accesible xml file with keys for UIManager, difference missing important bugs, dark side has own bugs, but are described on one place

Comment: So we can not paint TextField when MouseOver by custom L&F based on Nimbus?